# A general linux file permissions question: Apache and WordPress

Tags: linux, apache, wordpress, permissions

I moved from a shared hosting to a VPS a few weeks ago and I'm having these annoying permission issues with WordPress. You know you can download and upgrade plugins (and wordpress itself) from the admin panel, but since I moved it started asking me my FTP credentials, which is kinda slow when I have to update ~20 plugins.

I think this should be some kind of rights issue. I looked that the shared hosting wordpress files, they all belong to the username and group kovshenin (kovshenin:kovshenin) and the files are -rw-r--r-- and the directories are drwx-r-xr-x.

On my VPS apache runs under apache:apache and my files are kovshenin:kovshenin. What should I do to make them readable and writable by both kovshenin and apache?

Also, I changed the permissions to 0777 for all files and folders of my wordpress installation, that allowed me to install and delete plugins without FTP, but when I pushed to automatic upgrade to WordPress 2.8.1 it still asked me for my FTP account. Is that a wp issue or did I miss something?

Thanks.

**Update**: I managed to run `id` and `id www-data` on the MediaTemple shared hosting. User kovshenin is in group kovshenin, and www-data is in group www-data. No more groups. What's the trick?

**Another update** Okay, I added the `apache` user to the `kovshenin` group, my wordpress files are `kovshenin:kovshenin` with `rw-rw-r--` permissions and `drwxrwxr-x` permissions on directories, but something is still wrong. The user `apache` can access the files and folders, I can use the online Themes and Plugins editor in the wordpress admin panel, I'm able to make changes to the .htaccess file from within wordpress, but plugin/theme installation still asks me for FTP credentials!

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying that apache running under apache:apache can access the WordPress files with www-data:www-data? If so then find out how it's managing that and configure it do the same with kovshenin:kovshenin.

Comment: No. www-data is on the shared hosting, and apache is running under www-data. The user apace is on my VPS and it's running under user and group apache:apache.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> What should I do to make them readable and writable by both kovshenin and apache?

- Create a new group, say "wordpress".
- Add both koveshenin and www-data users to the wordpress group.
- Change the group owner of all the files to wordpress (using chgrp).
- Make sure all the files are group writeable.
- **Set the g+s (setgid) permission bit on all the *directories* of interest.**
- Make sure kovshenin and apache's default umask includes group read & write permission.

The second last step is the trick.  It means that whenever kovshenin or apache creates a file in those directories, the group owner will be set to wordpress (instead of kovshenin or apache).

Comment: Okay this is closer, thanks so much, but how come the user www-data and kovshenin on the Media Temple shared hosting account don't have additional groups? What's that trick called? ;)

Comment: Hard to say, but the shared hosting account might be set up using phpsuexec.

Comment: Hey there caf, one more question. I changed the group owner of all the files and dirs in the wp folder to apache, the owner is still kovshenin, so it's kovshenin:apache and the rights are 0775, so both kovshenin and apache have rights to read write and execute files. Works fine. I did the g+s part, new files are created with kovshenin:apache, all fine, BUT, the rights for the new file are 755. How do I fix that for 775? Tried settings g+ws.. Doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Thanks once more.

Comment: Oh, sorry, that must be the umask.. =)

Comment: Yes, your umask is probably 0022, you need to set it to 0002.  By the way, kovshenin doesn't even need to be in the 'apache' group for this to work.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on how to set the umask ?
I'm running Debian and I've tried setting it in .bashrc for the user, however to no avail.

Comment: @Steffen: Setting it in `.bashrc` will work for normal user accounts; for `apache` started from `init.d`, you can add a line setting the umask in `/etc/default/apache2`.

Comment: I'll try that out, thanks.
Just one more question: setgid - is it a command or ? I tried typing setgid on Debian, and it didn't know it (could find anything through apt either)

Comment: @Steffen: The "setgid" bit is a file permissions bit - so it's set by `chmod`.  In particular, you want `chmod g+s` on the directories of interest.

Comment: @caf: Aaah excellent, then I get it :-)
Well I'll give it a try tonight, thanks alot for the elaboration.

Comment: I've gotten most of it to work, though I still have no luck with automatic updates in wordpress.

All files 775 (chmod), the owner is my user, and the group is wordpress. Furthermore I setup my users default group to be wordpress, and set g+s on all directories (and files I think, just did a * :-D)

Files are however still created with 644 rights, so my umask isn't in effect I guess.

Anyway that's a minor issue, what's more important is that wordpress still asks for FTP access. Could it perhaps be that wordpress must be the owner of the files ? (chown)

Comment: @Steffen: If wordpress isn't the owner, the files will have to be 644 (and the directories 2775).

Comment: @caf: what's the first 2 in the directories ? I always thought there was only owner group guest ?
Anyway all files and directories are 775 already.

Comment: Oh well I give up on it now, I'll just settle on FTP access to update, at least that works out of the box :-D

Comment: New directories are created with www-data:wordpress owner.  Subdirectories are created with www-data:www-data ownership.  How can I change that?

Comment: @ChristopherIckes: That means that whatever you're using to create the directories isn't copying the setgid bit to the new directories (the standard `/bin/mkdir` utility does do this).  You might need to manually `chmod g+s` the directories after they're created.

Comment: Is there a way that both users kovshenin and www-data could delete files within a particular directory, say the wordpress directory, regardless of which owner the file?

Comment: @ChristopherIckes: Yes - for an ordinary directory, a file can be deleted if the user has write permission on the directory containing the file, so just make sure the directories have group write permission set.

Comment: @caf what are your thoughts on this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18228351/how-make-var-www-contents-editable-by-ide. It looks same as this question

Comment: I'm sorry. What the two last sentences mean??

Answer (score 1):

You can give ownership to www-data according to [here](http://i.justrealized.com/2009/02/08/how-to-get-auto-update-working-in-wordpress/).

Run the following command in your WordPress directory (sudo required):

```
sudo chown -Rf www-data *
```

Works for Apache.

Comment: That works fine, but then I can't edit those files with my regular user and this is what freaks me out.. :(

Comment: Are they not still group owned by kovshenin? You ought to be able to still edit them if they are.

If not then you could try making the user kovshenin a member of the group that they are owned by and use newgrp to change your group to that before editing them.

Comment: They are group owned by kovshenin, but new files which I'll upload from the user kovshenin will become kovshenin:kovshenin and I'd have to chown again. I'm setting up the hosting for a few clients of mine and I'd like their files to be kovshenin:kovshenin style, not apache (or www-data). I wonder how MediaTemple did that..

Comment: You can add your regular user to the www-data group or you could also append sudo in the beginning of your command.

Comment: What command? Please read what I'm trying to do, it's not that simple.. There are no additional groups.

Comment: caf has an answer that you want.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your wordpress install directory is `/var/www/html` to mass change all the files and directories to the proper permission use:

```
sudo  find /var/www/html/ -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
sudo  find /var/www/html/ -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
```

To mass change the owner group of everything use:

```
sudo chgrp -R <desired_username>.<desired_groupname> /var/www/html
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it turning off PHP 'safe_mode' in plesk, now WP can create folders and move files without any problems.

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, adding `define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');` to wp-config.php might do the trick. Not sure that would have worked in '09 though. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25879884/lemp-wordpress-file-permissions-to-be-able-to-edit-upgrade-and-use-sftp-clien/25906743#25906743) for my similar case using nginx. I found that it was an essential step.