# apache and sftp permissions for wordpress automatic update in ubuntu

Tags: apache, wordpress, permissions, sftp, umask

It's my first time trying to set up Wordpress or any website on a cloud hosting. I am on Ubuntu server, and Wordpress is located in var/www/mydomain/public folder.

**What I want to achieve is this:** Both Wordpress (PHP) and SFTP users can access and modify the same files. And Wordpress should be able to do it's automatic update for plugins, etc.

**This is what I have done so far:**

- I have chmodded this folder to 775 to allow group read/write permissions.
- I have added apache user (www-data) and SFTP user (suser) both to group wp.
- I have made wp as the group owner of all files inside the wordpress folder.

**What works:**

- I can edit theme and plugin files with Wordpress's built-in theme/plugin editor.

**What does not work:**

- Wordpress update still asks for the FTP details to carry out the update
- When I create a new file with SFTP user, it's permissions will be 644, but they should be 775

**What I've tried**

- I have tried all the steps here (answer by caf): [A general linux file permissions question: Apache and WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113691/a-general-linux-file-permissions-question-apache-and-wordpress)
- I have tried this: http://jeff.robbins.ws/articles/setting-the-umask-for-sftp-transactions
- I have also tried adding umask 002 to my SFTP startup login files, but I do not know where they are located.

As far as I understand, the problem lies somewhere with the permissions/umask thing. I know very little about linux so this may be a stupid question with a simple solution, but I have no idea how to fix it.

**UPDATE:** I did not know that I would have to restart the ssh server. I did it with this `command /etc/init.d/ssh restart` and after that files created with SFTP have permissions 664 (as they are supposed to)
Also, it seems that Apache has to be restarted as well, with this command: `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

However, Wordpress *still* won't do automatic update (asks for FTP credentials)

Comment: Why it is off topic? I am still searching for solutions.

Answer (score 2):

If you're able to install the SSH2 PHP Module Wordpress will then give you the option to upgrade over SFTP.

In Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install libssh2-php
```

In CentOS (EPEL required):

```
sudo yum install php-pecl-ssh2
```

Comment: "E: Package 'libssh2-php' has no installation candidate" after tried your command for Ubuntu. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same thing with Wordpress updates, until I realized that Wordpress only supports FTP which, confusingly, SFTP is *not*. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPS):

> FTPS should not be confused with the SSH File Transfer Protocol
>   (SFTP), an incompatible secure file transfer subsystem for the Secure
>   Shell (SSH) protocol. It is also different from Secure FTP, the
>   practice of tunneling FTP through an SSH connection.

I'm still trying to figure out if there's a secure way to do Wordpress updates automatically; I don't know yet whether or not FTPS is truly secure.