# Update wordpress to 4.8.1 failed, how to update by clicking the link?

Tags: wordpress, apache

[image]

Above are my failing message. I tried to adjust /var/www/html/wp-content to 777. Doesn't work.

What should I do to update to latest WP by clicking the update link in WP-Admin?

I am using VPS of Ubuntu 16, Apache2, not goDaddy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [apache and sftp permissions for wordpress automatic update in ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232282/apache-and-sftp-permissions-for-wordpress-automatic-update-in-ubuntu)

Comment: @cale_b Why they mark the question in your link off topic? The managers are very useless.

Comment: Because it's duplicate.  Did you read the answers? Did you try them? What was the result?

Answer (score 0):

Try this -
Using FTP, got to your root directory and delete the .maintenance file.
This file contains a variable that is used by the wp_maintenance function. It looks something like this:

```
<?php $upgrading = 1302133706; ?>
```

And then try updating again

Comment: This is not the answer.  The question is _how to update_.

Comment: Delete maintenance file and try updating wordpress again

Comment: there is no .maintenance file in "/root" or "/var/www/html". What do you mean by "root" directory?  @ParthPatel

Comment: @NicolasS.Xu root of your app

Comment: @ParthPatel The root of my app is "/var/www/html", but there is no .maintenance file.