# Unable to load my website subpages after creating ssl certificates without https subpages are opening normally

Tags: wordpress, apache, amazon-web-services, web, web-hosting

My web site was working fine via `http` with postname option in Permalink. Recently I have activated `https` (i.e. ssl) for my website. After that only home page is working, sub pages are not working. For default Permalink settings `https` is working. I have purchased wild card ssl certificates from godaddy, they have given me 2crt files. One starts with `b811adugdfdfd.crt` and another is `gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt`. I have uploaded both certificates in apache server and a key file. am I doing any mistake?? Website landing page is working with `https` but not subpages. Thanks in advance. Is the issue with `SSL`, or `.htaceess` or permalinks?

Comment: No luck... ????

Comment: I found the solution. 

in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
<Directory /path/to/site>
     #add the following setting to allow .htaccess in your web dir to work
     AllowOverride All

     #other settings ---

</Directory>

Comment: then restart apache

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A general linux file permissions question: Apache and WordPress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113691/a-general-linux-file-permissions-question-apache-and-wordpress)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your using "apache" Add directory Permission in SSL configuration of apache

//Directory /var/www/html/demoproject/public  //
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
//Directory//

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few quick checks that might help (If your SSL settings are all fine):

1. Make sure that under General Settings Page you have changed the site address URLs from http://domainname.com to https://domainname.com.
2. Try to check pages by forcing it to SSL with the help of a plugin [WordPress HTTPS](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-https/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have changed in general settings from http://subdomain.domain.com to https://subdomain.domain.com but same issue working subpages working with http but not https.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have changed in general settings from http://subdomain.domain.com to https://subdomain.domain.com but same issue working subpages working with http but not https

Comment: Try to force the pages to SSL with the plugin I have mentioned and check if your problem is resolved

Comment: when I installed the plugin the website is not working with http and https.

Answer (score 1):

Write this code in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```